# how do I stop ads in browser which are coming even after installing adblock

Tags: google-chrome, web, block

Adds, as shown in the pic highlighted in red, are popping up every time I open a new tab. Is there any way to get rid of this kind of bugs

Answer (score 0):

If the source of the ads, i.e the domain name, is different that the host website, you can add an entry for the origin of the add in your local dns.
for example lets suppose that you're visiting example.com, and there's an ad on it from adsite.com.

In Windows:
open this file in notepad `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 adsite.com
```

In Linux:
open this file in your text editor `/etc/hosts` and this line:

```
127.0.0.1 adsite.com
```

Although if the ad is on the same domain as the host website, and ad blockers don't detect it, then it's gonna be hard to get rid of it.

EDIT: I'm not 100% sure about the windows path, only 99% :-D